# Exporting composite of two superimposed images in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Writing a program to
a) upload an image
b) superimpose a logo (second image)
c) drag and resize the logo
d) save the result as a PNG

I thought I'd fixed the problem once I divided the .paste() coordinates by the exact size of the canvas, but the logo still drifts out of position upon export. It drifts up and left when I place it bottom right. When the logo is closer to the middle, there is less error. Any help would be much appreciated.

(In the export function, the bg_img width and height are used to create a new (blank) Image. Then bg_img is pasted on this at 0,0. This first part of the function works fine.

Next, the coordinates of the logo are pulled in. These are the coordinates on the canvas where the centre of the logo is to be found. The coordinates are converted to the coordinates relative to the bg_img. Then they have half the size of the logo subtracted from them to represent the top-left
corner of the image. The image is converted to RGBA and then pasted on to img_export at the newly calculated coordinates.)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk, ImageOps, Image

# Save PNG File _______________________

def export():
    global bg_img, logo_img, logo_id

    width = bg_img.width
    height = bg_img.height

    img_export = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height))
    img_export.paste(bg_img, (0,0))

    logo_x, logo_y = canvas.logo_coords
    logo_x = int(width / 1001 * (logo_x - logo_img.width // 2))
    logo_y = int(height / 1001 * (logo_y - logo_img.height // 2))
    print(f"coordinates = {logo_x, logo_y}")

    l_img_alpha = logo_img.convert("RGBA")
    img_export.paste(logo_img, (logo_x, logo_y))

    file = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.png')
    img_export.save(file, "PNG")

# Logo Upload & Placement ______________________

def start_drag(event):
    widget = event.widget
    widget.startX = event.x
    widget.startY = event.y
    widget.logo_coords = (widget.startX, widget.startY)

def drag(event):
    widget = event.widget
    deltaX = event.x - widget.startX
    deltaY = event.y - widget.startY
    widget.move(widget.logo_id, deltaX, deltaY)

    widget.logo_coords = (widget.startX, widget.startY)
    print(widget.logo_coords)
    widget.startX = event.x
    widget.startY = event.y

def render_logo():
    global logo_img, logo_id

    logo_rendered = ImageTk.PhotoImage(logo_img)
    if hasattr(canvas, 'logo_id'):
        x, y = canvas.coords(logo_id)
        canvas.delete(logo_id)
        logo_id = canvas.create_image(x, y, image=logo_rendered)
    else:
        logo_id = canvas.create_image(500, 500, image=logo_rendered)

    canvas.logo_rendered = logo_rendered
    canvas.logo_id = logo_id

    canvas.tag_bind(logo_id, "<ButtonPress-1>", start_drag)
    canvas.tag_bind(logo_id, "<B1-Motion>", drag)

def enlarge():
    global logo_img

    incr_width = int(logo_img.width * 1.33)
    incr_height = int(incr_width*logo_img.height/logo_img.width)
    logo_img = logo_img.resize((incr_width, incr_height), Image.LANCZOS)
    render_logo()

def reduce():
    global logo_img

    smaller = (int(logo_img.height * 0.88), int(logo_img.width * 0.88))
    logo_img.thumbnail(smaller)
    render_logo()

def upload_logo(event=None):
    global logo_img, bg_img, user_prompt

    file_formats = [('Jpg', '*.jpg'), ('PNG', '*.png'), ('JPEG', '*.jpeg')]
    logo_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=file_formats)

    logo_img = Image.open(logo_path)
    logo_img.thumbnail((100,100))
    render_logo()

    canvas.logo_coords = (500,500)

    if logo_img:
        user_prompt.destroy()
        enlarge_button = Button(text="enlarge logo", command=enlarge, highlightbackground="#6D3939")
        enlarge_button.place(x=555, y=0)
        reduce_button = Button(text="reduce logo", command=reduce, highlightbackground="#6D3939")
        reduce_button.place(x=333, y=0)
        export_button = Button(text="Export", command=export, highlightbackground="#6D3939")
        export_button.place(x=444, y=955)

# Image Upload & Render Background ______________________

def upload_picture(event=None):
    global bg_img, user_prompt

    file_formats = [('Jpg', '*.jpg'), ('PNG', '*.png'), ('JPEG', '*.jpeg')]
    bg_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=file_formats)

    bg_img = Image.open(bg_path)
    if bg_img.height > 909 or bg_img.width > 909:
        bg_img.thumbnail((909, 909))
    else:
        bg_img = ImageOps.contain(bg_img, (909, 909))
    bg_img_rendered = ImageTk.PhotoImage(bg_img)
    canvas.bg_img_rendered = bg_img_rendered
    canvas.create_image(500,500, image=bg_img_rendered)
    print(bg_img.width, bg_img.height, bg_img)

    upload_button.destroy()
    user_prompt = Button(text="add your logo", command=upload_logo, highlightbackground="#6D3939")
    user_prompt.place(x=444, y=0)

# User Interface ______________________

window = Tk()
window.title("Watermark")
window.resizable(True, True)

canvas = Canvas(window, width=1001, height=1001, bg="#6D3939")
canvas.grid(column=1, row=1)

upload_button = Button(text='upload your image', command=upload_picture, highlightbackground="#6D3939")
upload_button.place(x=444, y=444)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: If the problem is about creating the image and then saving it, you can probably remove about half of that example. To reproduce the problem it doesn't seem that we need to drag and drop anything -- you can just hard-code the coordinates for the purpose of this example, eliminating all of the drag and drop code. See [mcve] for more help on creating an example.

Comment: Why do you change `canvas.logo_coords` inside `start_drag()`? Also the update of the new `canvas.logo_coords` inside `drag()` is incorrect.  Actually you don't need the attribute `logo_coords` at all because it can be retrieved by calling `canvas.coords(logo_id)`.

Comment: @BryanOakley you're right, thanks for sending that article. Having commented out the drag functions I still have the same issue

Comment: @acw1668 that's a good point. I've replaced those lines with canvas.coords(logo_id) but am still having the same problem.

Comment: The way to calculate `logo_x` and `logo_y` inside `export()` is wrong, try thinking how to do it again.

Answer (score 1):

Having written it all out on paper and used print statements at every stage, I found out where my export() calculation was going wrong. I came up with this instead, and now the logo exports in perfect position.

```
logo_starting_x = int(bg_img.width/2)
logo_starting_y = int(bg_img.height/2)
logo_abs_x, logo_abs_y = canvas.coords(logo_id)

logo_x = int((logo_abs_x - 500) + logo_starting_x - (logo_img.width // 2))
logo_y = int((logo_abs_y - 500) + logo_starting_y - (logo_img.height // 2))
```